# Trouble adding a certificate in Charles Proxy on Ubuntu due to unclickable Import button

Tags: charles-proxy

I faced with the problem in Charles proxy to add a certificate on Ubuntu. In documentation there are steps to add certificate in Windows and MacOS, but nothing for Linux.

[image: window, Import button unactive]

Tried to search some information, those were unhelpful or outdated.

Comment: You may better ask on an Ubuntu specific site like https://askubuntu.com what are the reasons Ubuntu refuses to import a certificate.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your comment, but I already did. Strange but I have first comment here from you, not on UbuntuAsk.)

Comment: BTW you don't have to obfuscate the screen shot of a certificate. Charles generates them on first start and it shouldn't be a probleme. You could even upload the file somewhere. CA and server certificates should not contain any personal information.

Comment: @Robert well these blurred places are the name of the computer. I prefer to put aside all personal information when posting on the internet.

And yeah, you are absolutely right, it's generated at the very beginning. Tried to download it and install manually, no result. Or I did something wrong, tried many different ways.

Comment: I didn't knew that Charles includes the PC name in it's certificates. Is it possible that the import dialog only allows to continue if you open the details section, or after certain seconds the dialog has to be in focus? Or install is disabled because it is already installed.

Comment: @Robert I'm not sure if you can say that it includes the name, but clearly preserve in the Identity, Verified by and Common name under the Detail tab. To go through Details section doesn't open Import possibilities, and I don't understand why is it red too. There are no any additional errors messages.